# Python Flask Application with waitress as an Windows Service

Tags: python, flask, windows-services, pywin32, waitress

I am trying to get a Flask Application on a Windows Server running as a service. I want to use the pywin32 package and I get to the point, where the Windows Service gets installed, but when I try to start the Service following error occurs:

> The Flask Application service failed to start due to the following
> error:  The service did not respond to the start or control request in
> a timely fashion.

And in another Log, I see this error:

> The description for Event from source Python Service cannot be found.
> Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your
> local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or
> repair the component on the local computer. If the event originated on
> another computer, the display information had to be saved with the
> event. The following information was included with the event:
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'servicemanager' The specified
> resource type cannot be found in the image file

Even when I do “pip install servicemanager”.

My run.py is a simple hello world to be sure that no source is creating these errors:

```
from flask import Flask
from waitress import serve

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=3030, threads=4)
```

If the run.py gets started manually everything is working as expected.

The service.py:

```
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import sys
import os
from run import app
from waitress import serve

class FlaskService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = 'FlaskService'
    _svc_display_name_ = 'Flask Application'

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
        self.is_alive = True

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)
        self.is_alive = False

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        import logging
        logging.basicConfig(
            filename=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'service.log'),
            level=logging.INFO
        )
        sys.stderr = sys.stdout = open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'service.log'), 'a+', buffering=1)

        logging.info("Service is starting")
        self.main()

    def main(self):        
        serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=3030, threads=4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(FlaskService)
```

What I did:

1. Create the ENV
2. Install all dependencies in the ENV including pywin32
3. Run the service.py as administrator with activated VENV

The output looks good:

> Installing service FlaskService copying host exe
> 'C:\Users\x\Desktop\Python
> \venv\lib\site-packages\win32\pythonservice.exe' ->
> 'C:\Users\x\Desktop\Python \venv\pythonservice.exe' Service installed

The Service is also installed but when I try to start the service, I am facing the above errors.